# Exclude a pod from updating

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I use Cocoapods. I have made some changes to a 3rd party library and if I run `pod update`, all those changes would get replaced. Running `pod install` does the same thing.

Is there a way to exclude a pod from updating? Or a way to install a single pod without affecting others?

Answer (score 12):

**At last Found the Solution.**

It will install pod without any repository update if you already have the library in the project,else will download

```
pod install --no-repo-update
```

If you want to update specific libraries  you can use :

```
pod update [POD_NAME...]
```

Answer (score 11):

I know this topic is pretty old but someone might come here after an answer, so here it is:

from https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/pull/7524

`--exclude-pods` option to `pod update` command.

> It allows to skip the update operation for specific pods.

Comment: This answer works. Here is an example of how to use it to update everything except Alamofire. You have to add this to the command line in terminal: `$ pod update --exclude-pods=Alamofire` Every other pod except Alamofire will be updated

Answer (score 7):

Yes, just specify the version you want to install, like if you want to keep using `AFNetworking` 1.3 and not upgrade to 2.*:

```
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 1.3.2'
```

Comment: I have specified the version numbers to all the pods. Still the changes made to them get replaced with a fresh copy.

Comment: That is due to the fact that pods it self is updated and now works a bit differently. So it will update to the version you specify and after which it will not update it any more.

Comment: The strange thing is I specified the latest version number and still it gets updated. The output is something like this. `<podname> 1.3.5 (was 1.3.5)`

Comment: That is because cocoapods itself it updated between the last time you used it to update the pods. That changed some things internally. But since it is still retrieving the same version it should not matter.

Answer (score -1):

Please check this discussion: 
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/760

One possible solution for now to update only a single pod would be:

```
Remove specific pod from Podfile
pod install
Re-add specific pod to Podfile
pod install
```

Comment: By removing you mean removing the pod I don't want to be updated?

Comment: Okay. But when I re-add it and run `pod install`, wouldn't it get a new copy instead of the one with the changes I made?

Comment: After first pod install You will have updated all libs, except which you modified. This is what you want. So You are right, the last pod install will update all 3rd party libs(this command not necessary for your case ).

Comment: I would not do this, since removing the pod form the Podfile will remove the library as soon as you ruin the pod install.

Comment: @rckoenes Thanks for your comment, I think my answer was wrong(sorry for that). So for final solution you can do following: 1. change pod file as suggested rckoenes, 2. keep your changes somewhere else 3. update pod 4. merge your saved changes on particular 3rd party lib sources. Thanks.

Comment: is this suppose to be real useable syntax?