# Exclude specific pods from install or update

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, podfile

I have few pods in my projects which are installed through Private pods. All the pods are pushed to the remote repository.

Now I want to exclude private pods from **pod install** API.

I referred : [Exclude a pod from updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24258056/exclude-a-pod-from-updating#32986006) and works fine using

> pod install --no-repo-update

I want to share my code to other person  who doesn't have access to my private pods, but when he runs **pod install** api just skips excludes private pods are they are already there in the repository.

Is there anyway to add some params in **Podfile** so that he doesn't have to add **--no-repo-update**, as in this process we have manually check and update the other pods by using

> pod update [POD_NAME...]

One person has suggested one way in https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/979 but I don't how to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The easy way is to fix the version number of your pods, so it won't be edited :

```
pod 'AFNetworking', '= 2.6'
```

Comment: Thanks, but context is different, pod is already installed in my project, if I run pod install , internally it will try to access remote for each pod repos and for one of my there is no access as it is internal and my pod will end up throwing error. 

I tried this :
pod 'MyAwesome', :path => 'path_for_pod', :tag => '0.1.0'
which worked fine but one only problem it is always fetching latest version i.e 0.1.9 in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I have found an alternate solution,

You can download the private pods locally and mention the path to the local folder in Podfile so that other can just use **pod install** or **pod update** and no need to change anything for user

ex:

```
pod 'MyPrivatePod', :tag => '0.1.3', :git => 'local_path_for_pod'
```

**Note:** You can mention local_path_for_pod as absolute path or relative path 
***ex:*** relative path could be **'../MyPrivatePod'** where MyPrivatePod is downloaded in parent folder of project repo.

This will enable the users who doesn't have access to remote repo can use the private pods. User can access only versions till the **MyPrivatePod** was downloaded.